# How to add exact shape & coordinates when create image map HTML?

Tags: html, imagemap

I am looking at this responsive image map [image map](http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html#blossom).

This image has different figures once you click on them and by doing so you will see exact shape to be selected.

What tool to use to create image-map and to have an exact shape of the image with corresponding coordinates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He used Adobe Fireworks. Fireworks was part of Adobe CS up to CS6. No longer part of the Adobe Creative Cloud Suite.

A guide on making image maps in Fireworks is at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/fireworks/cs/using/WS4c25cfbb1410b0021e63e3d1152b00d35d-7fe6.html

If you don't have Fireworks available, a similar process is available in Dreamweaver https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/image-maps.html or in Photoshop